# ServiceNow REST API - Querying tables - grouping conditions

Tags: servicenow-rest-api

I need to query tables in ServiceNow via its REST API while using multiple conditions grouped as following:

( (Condition1 AND Condition2) OR (Condition3 and Condition4) ) AND Condition5 AND Condition6

Does anyone know if this is possible, and if so, how? I've looked into the [documentation](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/newyork-platform-user-interface/page/use/common-ui-elements/reference/r_OpAvailableFiltersQueries.html) but I'm not able to understand if it explains how to solve my problem.

Edit 1: I forgot to mention that I did try using parenthesis in my REST calls but it has not worked.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've figured out how to do it is using the ^NQ (New Query) operator.

In SQL the query would look like this:

```
WHERE [state] IN (16,17) AND ([assigned_to] = 'value1' OR [assignment_group] IN ('x','y','z'))
```

So my query looks like this:

```
sysparm_query=stateIN16,17^assigned_to=value1^NQstateIN16,17^assignment_groupINx,y,z
```

So you're actually duplicating the common filter (state) and using different filters on each side of the ^NQ.

I guess you could say it would be the equivalent of a UNION in SQL.

```
SELECT * FROM [wm_task] WHERE [state] IN (16,17) AND [assigned_to] = 'value1'
UNION
SELECT * FROM [wm_task] WHERE [state] IN (16,17) AND [assignment_group] IN ('x','y','z')
```